# Can we say "Had Einstein used his spare time on something more useful for the society, ..."

Tags: grammar

The complete sentence is :

> **Had** Einstein used his spare time on something more useful for the society, the improvement of our knowledge of the nature of the universe would have been greatly delayed.

I move "Had" to the head of the sentence to make it a little uncommon.

Comment: If "society" refers to people in general, rather than a specific society, the "the" before it should be omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a proper conditional statement, so yes, you can certainly frame it like this.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the contrary to fact usage of the not-quite-dead-yet subjunctive.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Assuming it's me you'd like to elaborate, the past conditional would go like this: If I knew that information when I finished school, I've forgotten it now. (Maybe I knew it, maybe I didn't.)  Contrast with a typical contrary to fact conditional: If I had known you were coming, I would have hidden the vodka. (The point is that I _didn't_ know you were coming.) It could also be phrased, "Had I known..." It looks like a past perfect, but is actually past tense subjunctive mood.